# Design decisions about computational hardware for small mechatronics project

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, raspberry-pi, design, robotics

I've recently started learning electronics/mechatronics. As part of my studies, I've been reading about devices such as RaspberryPi, Arduino, etc, and I'm interested in experimenting with such devices.

I have what would, I guess, be considered a "design" question. Let's say I wanted to undertake a small robotics project. Furthermore, let's assume that I wanted this small project to just be something that remains connected (via usb, say) to a computer. In terms of the electronics involved here, how would I go about making design decisions about whether such a device would require a microcontroller (such as Arduino), a self-contained computer (such as Raspberry Pi), or whether no such separate computational hardware is required, since it is connected to the computer (and the computer can do all the computational stuff itself)? Specifically, what I'm actually asking is a beginner technical question: Does such a robotic device, as described, require having some separate, additional computational device, such as an Arduino or Raspberry Pi, in order to operate (since this might be required to interface with the computer, or something), or are such devices superfluous if it is connected directly to the computer already (that is, the computer can somehow (through the more "primitive" (for lack of a better term) circuit board elements) directly interface with, and control, the robotics device? Furthermore, if the latter is the correct answer, then is there any situation in which, despite being connected directly to the computer, that it would be a good design decision to *also* include one of these separate pieces of computational hardware in the device (say, for computationally intensive tasks (although, it *is* connected directly to the (much more powerful) computer, so I'm not sure that this would make any sense))?

I'm not sure if this would get covered later at some point in my textbooks, so I thought that I might as well ask now, just in case it never gets covered and I forget.

This probably heavily relates to "control systems" or "control engineering", but I am very new to all of this, so I'm not yet familiar with all of the specifics of hardware.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: I started with electronics 55+ years ago (:-)). Your questions as to what is "best" involved personal decisions based on preferences, experiences, available resources and a lot more. The fact that I (or anyone else) would do things a certain way does not mean that is best for you. || For a "small" robotics project that was USB tethered to a PC I'd personally invariably use a "computer" on board. In most simple cases an Arduino would be very adequate. This allows any complexities re USB transmission and timing to be avoided where desirable. Things like wheel speed sensors thjat may require ...

Comment: ... interupts or local timers or real time response are harder and possibly impossible when a PC and USB link are interposed. Most PC OS's are not aimed at realtime control. You could eg flash or dim LEDs, drive motors with variable speed and/or differential steering, implement a line follower or implement self balancing and similar via a USB link but all of those are harder or vastly harder without local processing. Given the cost of an Arduino (under $US5 for a Chinese clone) not using one seems to me to make little sense. Whether it makes the same sense to others may vary.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Ok, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Funnily enough, chapter **1.2 The design process** of my textbook *Mechatronics: Electronic Control Systems in Mechanical and Electrical Engineering*, seventh edition, by William Bolton, (obviously) discusses the design process.

Comment: But, does he agree with me? :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon With regards to your first comment, yes, but the author obviously goes into a lot more detail (since it is the focus of an entire subchapter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question honestly is too broad. You have these criteria:

1. Suitability of peripherals
2. Suitability of processing power
3. Ease of software development
4. Ease of hardware development

3 and 4 completely dwarf the other two criteria so much when starting out. When starting, just always assume you need a microcontroller in some form until you know for a fact from experience that you need something more.

Arduinos are pre-packaged microcontrollers with software crutches. An RPI is a pre-packaged application processor with an OS. An RPI is an advanced piece of hardware that you have no chance (or money) of building something similar from scratch on your own.

With an Arduino, you are eased into the software side (software crutches in the form of the Arduino programming language/environment) and the bare minimum on the hardware side so you can at least graduate onto bare microcontrollers and re-use the knowledge. You cannot do the same with an RPI because the hardware is too advanced.

Comment: I know my question was unclear, so I apologise for that. What I am asking is also an electronics question: For such a device (that is, a device that must be attached via usb to the computer), then does it even make sense for it to have an Arduino? Can't the computational stuff be done on the computer, and transmitted to the circuits of the robot? Isn't the Arduino (or RPI) superfluous in such a case? Or is there still a case to be made for having an Arduino (or RPI) as part of the robot? As you can see, this [...]

Comment: [...] is also a technical question about circuits and how they interface with computational devices. This specific question doubles as a design question.

Comment: @ThePointer There are two ways to connect something you build to a computer via USB: the real way, and the fake way. The real way is complicated. THe "fake" way is pretty easy. You get a UART-TTL to USB chip or cable (like from FTDI) and that makes the UART on your MCU appear as a Virtual COM port on the PC after the drivers are installed. Then you have a terminal with which to interface with (or write PC applications that communicate through it). If an Arduino has a UART, this method will work.

Comment: And this "fake" way is using devices like the Arduino? What is the real way?

Comment: For off-board processing, consider this: you receive data from the robot on your PC, do the heavy processing on your PC, and then send it back via USB. Great. What's sitting on your robot sending the data and interpreting and acting on the received data?

Comment: The real way is with real native USB drivers and unneeded for something like this. For example, if you wanted to make a flash drive you would need the real way. Using a UART-USB bridge is vastly easier and will work with anything that has a UART.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was concerned about. I'm assuming that you would then have to use some very low-level language to program the chips on the circuit board, or something like that? And this is why the Arduino is so much simpler?

Comment: Pretty much. The Arduino is simpler because it provides you with a dumbed down environment with pre-written functions to do common things. It holds your hand and shields you from the nitty-gritty of flipping configuration registers in the hardware of your MCU to configure everything. This is the kind of thing where you pore over the datasheet working through each register bit one-by-one reading what it does and setting it.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies what I was mainly asking about. Thank you again for taking the time to explain this!

Answer (score 1):

*what I'm actually asking is a beginner technical question: Does such a robotic device, as described, require having some separate, additional computational device, such as an Arduino or Raspberry Pi, in order to operate (since this might be required to interface with the computer, or something), or are such devices superfluous if it is connected directly to the computer already (that is, the computer can somehow (through the more "primitive" (for lack of a better term) circuit board elements) directly interface with, and control, the robotics device?*
(...)
*This probably heavily relates to "control systems" or "control engineering", but I am very new to all of this, so I'm not yet familiar with all of the specifics of hardware.*

"as described", your project is not well described.

Let's say that's a very simple robot, with wheels and motors, and the robot has sensors to find obstacles in its path, and change course in order to avoid them. Probably, for a very simple newbie's robot, Arduino should be enough.

But, if you have experiences only with Arduino, you will not be able to perceive when Arduino is not the best solution. Same for Raspberry Pi. If you only connect things to the PC, you will also loose the oportunity to learn how to use Arduino and Raspberry.

The objective of a beginner is LEARN. So, don't worry about these kind of options for now.

Just try experiments with both devices. The simplest robots can be made with Arduino; so, start with a simple Arduino robot.

If, in the future, you really hit the Arduino ceiling (and there are Arduinos more advanced than Uno, e.g. Mega) and want to add more complexity to the devices, you could adapt your project to Raspberry.

A personal advice: don't worry about this kind of thing for now. The only person that can make a perfect decision for your project is yourself, but, before making this decision, you have to learn a few things.

========================================================================

**EDIT after OP comment**

All the computational stuff can be done a computer. But... (keep reading).

If the computational stuff of the robot is done in a computer, you have to manage their communication: send data from robot's sensors to the computer, and send command signals from the computer to robot's motors. There was a time when a computer could send and receive binary data easily, using a parallel port. But this is not an option anymore.

If you want the computer and the robot communicating through USB (or through a serial-to-USB adapter), the robot needs to have a device to gather all the sensors' data and send them to the computer through an USB or serial data stream; the same device also has to get data from the USB or serial stream, and to parse and distribute this data (control signals for the robot's motors / actuators / lights / etc) to the robot's hardware. This device has to be built around a microcontroller capable of USB or serial communication, and a software has to be written to it.

But, if the computational stuff of a simple robot is not so complex at all, it is easier to process the data in the microcontroller itself, instead of using the microcontroller only for managing the USB data-exchange between robot's sensors & motors and the computer. And there is another great advantage: your robot becomes becomes independent of the computer: you will not need an USB or serial cable connecting one to another. If the processing of data is so much complex, or if there are too much data lines, there are powerfull microcontrollers to choose from.

Besides that, a Raspberry Pi is a computer itself, so, so it has more processing power than a generic microcontroller, AND, it also can gather binary data directly, that's the reason why it can be used in some of robots. But, Raspberry has somewhat limited capabilities in this area (only two PWM, no ADC), so, it is common that Raspberry's robots rely on a microcontroller for helping them to exchange data with the physical parts.

*If, for the sake of argument, the robot in your question is (must be) attached via usb to the computer, then does it even make sense for it to have an Arduino?*

Yes, because the USB (or serial) connection will require an Arduino, or PIC, or anoter microcontroller, to manage the data exchange between the computer and the robot. How would you make the sensor's data to fit in the USB stream?

*Can't the computational stuff be done on the computer, and transmitted to the circuits of the robot?*

Strictly, the answer is affirmative, the computational stuff CAN be done on the computer, and transmitted to the circuits of the robot.
BUT, this is so complicated, that is only worth if you really have a reason for this.

Comment: But my question is this: If, for the sake of argument, the robot in your question is (must be) attached via usb to the computer, then does it even make sense for it to have an Arduino? Can't the computational stuff be done on the computer, and transmitted to the circuits of the robot?

Comment: @ThePointer I edited the answer. Unfortunatelly, the browser cache prevented me of seeing the comments and the another answer from other users, which point to the same direction that I did, so, basically, I wrote something that already has been said.